# Maintaining navigation bar at top of page on IOS<5

Tags: jquery, ios, scroll, css-position

I've scoured the web and SO for solutions to the IOS<5 position:fixed problem and am wondering if this approach is doable with jQuery:

1.change nav bar div to position:absolute;

2.for every pixel that is scrolled dynamically add/subtract to the nav bar div top value.

Is this possible? Can jQuery detect scrolling and change the nav bar div top value dynamically without using too many resources?

Any comments and/or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds bad. You shouldn't have problems using the `fixed` position. If you have, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Fixed positioning isn't supported on anything older than IOS5 :(

Comment: You are right. Anyway, IOS  is quite old... :)